# Trigger Different Item Listener for each JComboBox inside JTable

Tags: java, jtable, row, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have column rendered with `JComboBox`, I have labels that show the amount of selected items for each type inside the `JComboBox`.

The problem is that I want to trigger different `ItemListener` for each row.

Now I have a column with all cells rendering `JComboBox`, but all trigger the same `ItemListener` why??

This is getting me nervous.

Here is my code:

```
listaPessoasModel = new DefaultTableModel(dadosPessoasTableColumn, 0);
listaPessoasTable = new JTable(listaPessoasModel);
listaPessoasTable.addKeyListener(newLineTableListener);
listaPessoasTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listaPessoasTable);
scrollPane.setBounds(205, 344, 385, 169);

TableColumn classeColumn = listaPessoasTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
classeColumn.setCellRenderer(new ClasseTableCellRender());

classeComboBox = new JComboBox<Classe>(new Vector<Classe>(Classe.allInstances()));
classeComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1); 
classeColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(classeComboBox));
classeComboBox.setRenderer(classeComboBoxRenderer);
classeComboBox.addItemListener(new classeComboBoxItemListener());
```

And here all my listeners and models:

```
private final class classeComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            Classe object = (Classe) e.getItem();
            System.out.println("ItemListener , objecto -> " + object);
            if(object != null && !newItemClasseComboControl){
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    updateLabelLugares(false, object);
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
                    updateLabelLugares(true, object);
            }
        }
    }

    static class ClasseTableCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ClasseTableCellRender() { super(); }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            if(value instanceof Classe)
                setText((value == null) ? "" : ((Classe) value).tipo().toString());
            else
                setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        }
    }

    private ListCellRenderer<Object> classeComboBoxRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                Object value,
                int index,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Classe classe = (Classe) value;
            if(value != null)
                value = classe.tipo().toString();

            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
                    index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    };
```

[image]

Above is a screenshot, showing what I am looking for.
The numbers are just to represent the idea, because this is still not working. I can't get the item listener to work individual for each row the way I want.
Because when I click to open the ComboBox it unselects the item that was previously selected.
I want the item listener to trigger only at item selection inside jcombobox, and individual for each cell of that column, so I can update the labels correctly.

Comment: _Now I have a column with all cells rendering JComboBox, but all trigger the same ItemListener why??_ You should maintain a flag for each row such that the flag says what the `JComboBox's ItemListener` of that row has to do when an selection is made.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Which method does that? how can I set a different item listener for each row? I am setting the itemlistener at tablecolumn ..

Answer (score 0):

That is just because may be its not getting proper Value for the Combobox use this TableCellEditor may be this will help.

```
class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        JComboBox combo;
        JSONObject response;

        public CheckBoxCellRenderer(JComboBox comboBox) {
            this.combo = new JComboBox();
            combo.setForeground(new Color(77, 75, 71));


            for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.getItemCount(); i++) {
                combo.addItem(comboBox.getItemAt(i));
            }


            combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent ie) {

                    System.out.println("Item state changed --");

                }
            });

        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            if (jtable.getSelectedRow() == row) {
                combo.setSelectedItem(value);
                combo.setActionCommand("" + row);
                return combo;
            }
            JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
            box.addItem("Pending");
            return box;
        }
    }
```